# highstock chart doesn't draw line continuations when connectNulls is true

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have configured a chart to use `connectNulls`.
What I am expecting is that the chart will draw lines to and from the edges of the chart:

(`x=0` and `x=n`)

How do I get the chart to draw lines from the left edge (for the missing data points) to the right edge.

```
var chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({

    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Connect Nulls'
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            connectNulls: true,
        }
    },

    series: [
    {
        type: 'line',
        name: data()[0][0],
        data: data()[0][1]
    },
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0qzrbnks/

**edit**

I have added a null value to series D0806, and it's still not connecting it?

Comment: `connectNulls` will draw lines between any points in the same series, even if there are null values in the same series inbetween. I.e. a series like this `data: [0, null, 10]`, will draw a line from `x: 0` to `x: 2`. Setting `connectNulls` to false, will in this case not draw the line. If you want lines that extend to and from end, you can either add fake points to the start and end of all lines. Or if these are all single point lines, use `plotLines`.

Comment: @ewolden i have updated the question, and inserted a null value into the D0806 series, which is not being connection. Will it not join to null on the edges?

Comment: No, unfortunately it will only connect across `null`s, not from and to. I.e. `data: [null, 1,null, 1, null]` will create a line from `x: 1` to `x: 3`.

Comment: damn that's disappointing - I will have to add invalid data points to get the line looking right.